# Random Forest error

Tags: google-earth-engine, remote-sensing, random-forest, machine-learning

I have tried a LULC classification using random forest algorithm in Google Earth Engine but error showing:

> Layer error: Property 'B2' of feature '0' is missing.

My script code: https://code.earthengine.google.com/e45af6557674fdc3a5fac9a6c1438a38

```
/**
 * Function to mask clouds using the Sentinel-2 QA band
 * @param {ee.Image} image Sentinel-2 image
 * @return {ee.Image} cloud masked Sentinel-2 image
 */
function maskS2clouds(image) {
  var qa = image.select('QA60');

  // Bits 10 and 11 are clouds and cirrus, respectively.
  var cloudBitMask = 1 << 10;
  var cirrusBitMask = 1 << 11;

  // Both flags should be set to zero, indicating clear conditions.
  var mask = qa.bitwiseAnd(cloudBitMask).eq(0)
      .and(qa.bitwiseAnd(cirrusBitMask).eq(0));

  return image.updateMask(mask).divide(10000);
}

var dataset = ee.ImageCollection("COPERNICUS/S2_HARMONIZED")
                  .filterDate('2023-3-01', '2023-3-28')
                  .filter(ee.Filter.lt('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE',1))
                  .map(maskS2clouds)
                  .median()
                  .clip(table);

var visualization = {
  min: 0.0,
  max: 0.3,
  bands: ['B8', 'B4', 'B3'],
};
Map.centerObject(table, 15);
Map.addLayer(dataset, visualization, 'satellite_image');

// create training data
var training=builtup.merge(waterbody).merge(vegetation).merge(bareland).merge(cropland);
var bands = ['B2', 'B3', 'B4', 'B5', 'B6', 'B7', 'B8', 'B8A', 'B11', 'B12'];
print(training)
var image = dataset.select(bands);
var lebel = 'class'

// overlay the points on the imagery to get training
var trainImage = image.sampleRegions({
  collection:training,
  properties:['lebel'],
  scale:10
});
print(trainImage.size());
print("total training", trainImage);


var trainingData = trainImage.randomColumn();
var trainset = trainingData.filter('random <= 0.80');
var testset = trainingData.filter('random > 0.80');
// print(trainset, 'Training sample');
// print(testset, 'Validation sample');


//RF Classifier Model Building
var RFclassifier = ee.Classifier.smileRandomForest(200).train({
  features: training,
  classProperty: 'lebel',
  inputProperties: bands
});

// classify the image
var classified = image.classify(RFclassifier);

// color plette
var Palette = [
  '008000', 
  'ffff00',
  '0000ff',
  'ff0000',
  '00ff00',
  ];
Map.addLayer(classified, {}, 'classified');
```

Comment: `table` object is not set as a public asset. Please change it so anyone can access the asset.